# Cómo actualizar datos (records) en un CSV con/en JAVA, sin Estructuras, Manual, Nivel: Novato)

Tags: java, csv, java-8

Estoy buscando la forma de actualizar datos en un CSV usando JAVA, que sea de forma simple, manual, sin uso de Estructuras de datos o soluciones de mayor nivel, sino, puro Progra 1, jaja, para los que están en la U.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Este tipo de aportes son bienvenidos, pero para respetar el formato del sitio, debes publicar una pregunta y luego publicar la respuesta a la misma. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una solución sencilla, sin uso de Estructuras de Datos y/o otras soluciones complejas que usan muchos programadores avanzados, ya que parte del principio mío, un estudiante de Primer Año. Comí muchas horas de sueño para entender cómo funcionan las cosas en JAVA, los tipos de objetos, documentación, cosas que uno no le dicen y mucho menos los programadores avanzados tienen el agrado de explicar. Espero aprecien el aporte. RECUERDEN, si no entienden su solución, papel y lápiz, eso hice yo para esta y me salió después de 15 intentos jaja.

### Solución reducida:

Irá leyendo y copiando todos los datos de un CSVOriginal hasta que encuentre el idUsuario que deseamos actualizar, reemplazamos los datos con los nuevos y luego copiará el resto pendiente para tener el archivo completo de nuevo. Entiendase que esta solucion crear un archivo nuevo a partir del archivo original

### Solución pseudocódigo:

1. Método recibe por parámetro un String [] **infoNuevaUsuario** y un
   int **idUsuario**.
2. Se crea un objeto a partir del **CSVOriginal** que ocupamos leer.
3. Crea un **archivoCSVTemporal**.
4. Ira iterando sobre cada linea del **CSVOriginal** y copiando las
   lineas en el **archivoCSVTemporal**.
5. Por cada iteración buscará si en esa linea esta el **IdUsuario** que
   ocupamos actualizar.
6. Sí encuentra el id que es igual a **idUsuario**, sobreescribe los
   datos con la informacion **infoNuevaUsuario** recibida por
   parametro, caso contrario, seguirá leyendo y copiando cada linea del
   **CSVOriginal** en el **archivoCSVTemporal**.

(Queda pendiente solo renombrar el archivo archivoCSVTemporal que se obtiene y borrar el CSVOriginal)

Espero sus comentarios de mejoras al codigo, desde una perspectiva de novato, ya que la idea es que sirva de apoyo a la gente que no se nos permitió en ese momento usar soluciones avanzadas, librerías externas (dependencies), sino pura mente y de forma manual.

Atributos que use en la clase (es cuestión de modificarlos a gusto)

```
private final String pathDBUsuarios = "src/projectDatabase/usuarios.csv";
public static final String SEPARADOR = ",";
private final String pathDBTemp = "src/projectDatabase/tempDB.csv";
```

Método principal

public boolean guardarDatosUsuario(String [] array, String idUsuario) {

```
    /* 
        BufferedWriter: Escribe texto a una salida de texto, almacenando los mismo datos 
        a como se reciben para una eficaz escritura de los caracteres, arreglos y lineas
    */

    // Crear archivo temporal donde se escribiran todos los datos y los nuevos
    boolean result = false;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    boolean primeraLinea = true;
    String tempPath;

    // BufferedReader debe ir en Try con el fin de probar el codigo, puede llegar a devolver errores
    try{

        // BufferedReader me permite leer datos de una entrada de datos recibida (como un archivo en este caso)
        // FileReader: permite leer "Streams" de datos y de archivos (Steam: fuente o destino de bytes) Streams
        // mas comunes --> archivos.
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathDBUsuarios));

        // Almacenar una linea del objeto 'br' en una variable tipo String.
        String linea = br.readLine();

        // Se crea el archivo temporal que almacenara
        tempPath = crearArchivoTemp();

        // Crear un ciclo que permita leer cada linea del objeto mientras no sea NULA
        while(linea != null) {

            // Separar la linea leída con el separador definido previamente
            String[] campos = linea.split(SEPARADOR);

            if(primeraLinea){

                escribirEnTemp(campos,tempPath);
                primeraLinea = false;

            }else{

                if(idEncontrado(campos, idUsuario) == true) {

                    escribirEnTemp(array,tempPath);

                }else{

                    escribirEnTemp(campos,tempPath);

                }

            }

            // Volver a leer otra línea del fichero
            linea = br.readLine();

        }

        br.close();

    }catch(IOException e) {
        // Cierro el buffer de lectura
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException err2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo no existe", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }


    return result;

}
```

Método para escribir en el archivo temporal

```
public void escribirEnTemp(String [] array, String path) {

        /*
            Agrega la informacion recibida al CSV. La informacion se obtiene por
            medio de un arreglo son sus valores previamente limpiados.
        */

        try {

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path, true);

            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {

                int contadorComas = (array.length - 1);

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    bw.write(array[i]);
                    if(i < contadorComas ) {
                        bw.write(",");
                    }
                }

                bw.write("\n");
                bw.flush();

            }

        }catch(IOException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo no existe", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

    }
```

Método para crear archivo temporal

```
public String crearArchivoTemp() {

        File temp;

        String path = "src/projectDatabase/tempFile.csv";

        try {

            // Crear nuevo objeto en Path dado + nombre de archivo
            temp = new File(path);

            if(temp.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("Archivo temporal creado correctamente");
            }

        }catch(IOException e) {

            System.err.println("El archivo no se pudo crear pues ya existe o bien contacte a su programador");

        }

        return path;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución propuesta no es Clara, y creo que posee opiniones que no son relevantes a la solución y un tanto ofensivas...

dicho esto quisiera hacer referencia a este BlogPost: [How to read and parse CSV file in Java - mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/)
en la lectura de mkyong, se propone una solución donde básicamente hace un Split, pero esto expone problemas donde el código no cumple con la especificación de CSV [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) e inclusive el uso de `String.Split()` no es la mejor solucion al problema dado a que Split utiliza Regular Expressions y puede hacer mas lenta el procesamiento de datos.

por tanto, para solucionar la lectura de un CSV se debe hacer de una forma más compleja:

```
package com.csv;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * ligeramente modificada de la version de mkyong
 */
public class CSVUtils {

private static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';
private static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE = '"';

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String csvFile = "archivo.csv"; //-> the cvs path here 
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(csvFile))) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String linetoprint = "";
            for (String x : parseLine(scanner.nextLine())) {
                linetoprint += String.format("\"%s\",", x);
            }
            //remover la ultima ","
            linetoprint = linetoprint.substring(0, linetoprint.length() - 1);
            System.out.println(linetoprint);
            writeLineToFile(linetoprint);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

public static void writeLineToFile(String data) {
    try {
       Path tmp= Files.write(Paths.get("myfile.csv"), (data+System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND,StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //manejar errores
        
    }
}

public static String[] parseLine(String cvsLine) {
    //if empty, return!
    if (cvsLine == null || cvsLine.isEmpty()) {
        return new String[]{};
    }
    //para evitar hacer este codigo mucho mas largo usamos un ArrayList
    //sino habria que agregar como 50 lineas 
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuffer curVal = new StringBuffer();
    boolean inQuotes = false;
    boolean startCollectChar = false;
    boolean doubleQuotesInColumn = false;
    char[] chars = cvsLine.toCharArray();
    OUTER:
    for (char ch : chars) {
        if (inQuotes) {
            startCollectChar = true;
            if (ch == DEFAULT_QUOTE) {
                inQuotes = false;
                doubleQuotesInColumn = false;
            } else {
                //Fixed : allow "" in custom quote enclosed
                if (ch == '\"') {
                    if (!doubleQuotesInColumn) {
                        curVal.append(ch);
                        doubleQuotesInColumn = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    curVal.append(ch);
                }

            }
        } else {
            switch (ch) {
                case DEFAULT_QUOTE:
                    inQuotes = true;
                    //Fixed : allow "" in empty quote enclosed
                    if (chars[0] != '"' && DEFAULT_QUOTE == '\"') {
                        curVal.append('"');
                    }   //double quotes in column will hit this!
                    if (startCollectChar) {
                        curVal.append('"');
                    }
                    break;
                case DEFAULT_SEPARATOR:
                    result.add(curVal.toString());
                    curVal = new StringBuffer();
                    startCollectChar = false;
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    //ignore LF characters
                    continue;
                case '\n':
                    //the end, break!
                    break OUTER;
                default:
                    curVal.append(ch);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    result.add(curVal.toString());
    //se usa toArray con un array vacío para la inferencia del tipo de array
    //en lugar de llamar result.toArray() por que sino nos retorna 
    //array de objetos: Object[]
    return result.toArray(new String[]{});
}

}
```

por tanto. hacemos una revisión del uso de `DEFAULT_QUOTE` en este caso `"` para revisar si el `DEFAULT_SEPARATOR` en este caso `,` es realmente un separador o un texto.

con relación a la escritura utilizamos el método `writeLineToFile` al cual pasamos cada valor, sin embargo téngase en consideración que hacer escrituras line a línea son bastante ineficientes y lentas (computacionalmente hablando) pero como ejemplo es útil.

finalmente, algo que en esta respuesta no se toma en consideración es el Uso de `Charset` si el archivo y el sistema no comparten el mismo set de caracteres los resultados de las lecturas y escrituras pueden ser inconsistentes.